# In WordPress, how can I remove the parent page from my url?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My site will have parent pages with multiple children. It's important that the children don't show the parent in the URL for SEO and user reasons. Right now I have: `mysite.com/parent-title/child-title` what I want to end up with is `mysite.com/child-title`.

I've found and tried

```
function wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( 'magazine' != $post->post_type )
        return $post_link;

    $uri = '';
    foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
        $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
    }

    return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

But all that did is turn all my pages with a parent into a 404. It seems like a rewrite might be the best option but I'm not sure how to do a proper rewrite (not that great with regex).

Comment: maybe add rewrite rule helps you. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule or try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: I was looking at the `add rewrite` Just not sure how to use that to do what I want.

Comment: Than take a look into the plugin. That should work fine.

Comment: i have that installed, doesn't seem to be doing anything or have options.